# Share Docker container storage volume between containers

Tags: docker

As an exercise I'm trying to setup three Docker containers.

- `container1` (as a pure storage volume)
- `container2` (Java application)
- `container3` (as a pure storage volume)

Now, the Java application running on `container2`, which is using Apache Camel, should listen to file addition on the `container1` volume and transfer them to `container3` volume.

I was thinking about installing an FTP image on the storage containers,  but I think their volumes can be exposed.

What's the better approach for this usecase?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add volume pointing to the same directory :

- container 1 : /opt/deposite:/opt/data
- container 3 : /opt/done:/opt/data

container 2 could have 3 volumes :

- Volume 1 For his own data   **/opt/app:/opt/app**
- Volume 2 Shared volume with container 1 : **/opt/deposite:/opt/deposite**
- Volume 3 Shared volume with container 2 : **/opt/done:/opt/done**

Your java application could simple check the folder of the volume 2 with a batch , and depose file in the folder of the volue 3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u are right. Their volumes can be exposed and this isn't difficult to implement. For an example u can try to run the next prepared docker-file:

```
#########################################################################
version: '3.3'                                                            
services: 
#########################################################################

  container-1:
    container_name: "test-container1"
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    volumes:
      - "$HOME/data/container-1:/root/data"

    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo 'Hello world!' > \
      /root/data/someFileFromContainer-1"]
#########################################################################    

  container-2:
    container_name: "test-container2"
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    depends_on:
      - container-1
    volumes:
      - "$HOME/data:/root/data"

    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/sleep 3s && \
      mv /root/data/container-1/someFileFromContainer-1 /root/data/container-3/"]
#########################################################################

  container-3:
    container_name: "test-container3"
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    volumes:
      - "$HOME/data/container-3:/root/data"
    depends_on:
      - container-2

    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 5s && \ 
      cat /root/data/someFileFromContainer-1"]
#########################################################################
```

Try to execute to see result (data from file created in the first container / 'Hello world!'):

`docker-compose up -d && docker logs -f test-container3`

- $HOME/data/container-1 mounted to container-1
- $HOME/data mounted to container-2 (it can see and operate with subfolders)
- $HOME/data/container-3 mounted to container-3